# Altering jquery event object

Tags: jquery

Are there any pitfalls/ dangers to altering jquery's event object?

For example:

```
$('#myselector').trigger({type: 'click', myvariable: 'mycontent' })
```

The additional attribute 'myvariable' gets stored in the event object and I'm able to use it when handling the click event. However, this isn't explicitly outlined in the documentation anywhere - is this considered bad practice?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly fine, and actually it is in the documentation http://api.jquery.com/trigger/
Notice the bit about 'extraParameters'

Answer (score 1):

Trigger already allows for extra parameters to be passed to the event handler:

> **.trigger( eventType [, extraParameters] )**
>
> ---
>
> **eventType** A string containing a JavaScript event type, such as click or
>   submit.
>
> **extraParameters** Additional parameters to pass along to the event
>   handler.

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

So, you can do what you already have, or:

`$('#myselector').trigger('click', { myvariable: 'mycontent' });`

or:

`$('#myselector').trigger('click', 'mycontent');`

depending on how you want to handle the data.